# How to use forEach to update all values matching this criteria

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am creating a function for selecting/deselecting checkboxes representing objects in my array.

Currently I have:

```
 selectAll(allType: string, state) {

    this.modalData.columnPermissions.forEach(a =>
      a["can" + allType] = state 
    );

  }
```

(allType allows me to target "canRead" or "canWrite" keys depending on which SELECT ALL the user chooses from the top of 2 columns.)

This is working fine - however a scenario has now been introduced where if an object contains the property IDM=TRUE then "canWrite" should always be FALSE

I'm struggling on how to now adapt my selectAll function to exclude any object with a property of IDM=TRUE on the KEY canWrite

Any help is appreciated

Comment: `if(allType==='Read' || !a.IDM){...what you have...}`

Comment: Whats the data and what are you trying to achieve. You need to be much more clear with your question.

Comment: thanks depperm you helped me get to that solution - im new to es6 methods

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this with info from depperm

```
 this.modalData.columnPermissions.forEach(a => {
  if (allType === 'Write' && !a.IDM) {
    a["can" + allType] = state
  } else if (allType === 'Read') {
    a["can" + allType] = state
  }
 })
```